# Why do my UI elements disappear after executing paint();?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, paint

If I run my code without the paint() method, the UI appears fine, but after executing paint() the UI only appears after clicking on/hovering over the elements.

I do not know why this happens, I've read somewhere that I might not be calling upon the paint() method the right way or that my setVisible() is not correct but I'm not sure.

My main method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame.createGUI();

        if(list != null) {
            System.out.println(list.toString());
        }else{
            System.out.println("Het is niet gelukt om uw stoelen juist in te delen. De zaal zit vol.");

        }
    }
```

My createGUI method:

```
public void createGUI() {
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 110));
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    add(scrollPane);


    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setTitle("Bioscoop Challenge");
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container window = this.getContentPane();
    window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());



    resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
    seatAmountField = new JTextField("Seats total");
    nField = new JTextField("Seats wanted");
    methodButton = new JButton("Reservate");
    errorMessage = new JLabel("Error message field");

    resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            list = fillList(seatcount);
            frame.validate();
            frame.repaint();
        }
    });

    methodButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            list = fillSeats(n, list);
            frame.validate();
            frame.repaint();
        }
    });

    window.add(resetButton);
    window.add(seatAmountField);
    window.add(nField);
    window.add(methodButton);
    window.add(errorMessage);

    pack();
    validate();
    setVisible(true);

}
```

The paint method:

```
    public void paint (Graphics g) {

    int x = 215;
    int y = 200;
    int width = 40;
    int height = 60;


    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Color color;
            Color color2;
            if (list.get(i).IsFree()) {
                color = red;
                color2 = black;
            } else {
                color = black;
                color2 = red;
            }
            if (list.get(i).booked) {
                color = blue;
            }
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillRect(
                    (int) r.getX(),
                    (int) r.getY(),
                    (int) r.getWidth(),
                    (int) r.getHeight()
            );

            g.setColor(color2);
            g.drawString(list.get(i).seatNumber.toString(), (width + x) - ((width / 2) + (width / 2) / 2), (height + y) - (height / 2));

            x = x + 50;
            if (x == 1715) {
                x = 215;
                y = y + 80;
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        errorMessage = new JLabel("ERROR");
    }
}
```

Help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do my UI elements disappear after executing paint()?

```
public void paint (Graphics g) 
{
    ...
}
```

The paint() method is responsible for painting all the child components, but you don't invoke the default behaviour. The code should be:

```
public void paint (Graphics g) 
{
    super.paint(g);
    ...
}
```

However, that is still not the proper solution.

You should NOT be overriding paint()!!!

Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComopnent()` of a JPanel. Then you add the panel to the frame. Now you won't have any of these issues.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.